# How to create a different List if Stream is empty

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

is there a nice way to create a different List if stream is empty?

Here if `special` is empty I want to create a new `List` with another value.
But if `special` is not empty I want to create `List` based on `special`.
I don't know is there a nice way to combine these with a stream

Here is a not so nice solution

```
class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = "test";

        List<String> special = getSpecialVals();

        List<String> newVals = 
                special.isEmpty() ? 
                Arrays.asList(myString) : 
                special.stream().map(s -> 
                         createNewVal(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static public List<String> getSpecialVals() {
        // but can return empty list
        return Arrays.asList("One", "Two");
    }

    static public String createNewVal(String origVal) {
        return origVal.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t think there’s a better way than what you are already doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to have it as a single pipeline then you could do:

```
List<String> strings = 
      Optional.of(special)
              .filter(e -> !e.isEmpty())
              .map(l -> l.stream().map(s -> createNewVal(s))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList()))
              .orElseGet((() -> Collections.singletonList(myString)));
```

However, I wouldn't recommend proceeding with this approach simply because it's not the intended purpose of Optional.

instead, you would be better off with:

```
List<String> result;
if(special.isEmpty())
   result = Collections.singletonList(myString);
else
   result = special.stream().map(s -> createNewVal(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- The latter is definitely more readable hence causes less work for the
  brain in trying to figure out what's happening. ;)
- The latter also avoids creating an Optional instance leading to better efficiency

Answer (score 4):

If you insist on keeping it inside you stream pipeline you may do:

```
List<String> newVals = special.stream()
        .map(s -> createNewVal(s))
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                l -> l.isEmpty() ? Collections.singletonList(myString) : l));
```

I like your own code better.

As an aside, instead of `.map(s -> createNewVal(s))` you may use `.map(X::createNewVal)` (since your class is called `X`). Which to prefer is largely a matter of taste.